# GCP Quota request denied for GPU (All Regions) after "Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally."

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to learn the fast.ai course. This requires a GPU and I am trying to use GCP.
I am following this guide here: https://course.fast.ai/start_gcp.html

I attempted increasing the quota for GPU (All Regions) jus like the guide, by setting a limit of 1 but I got this email from the support:

*"Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this time. If

this is a new project please wait 48h until you resubmit the request or

until your Billing account has additional history."*

I asked them if this meant they could not increase my quota for GPU (All regions) and this was the reason:

*"Nevertheless, after careful evaluation on your project _______ we have determined that we are unable to grant your quota increase due to insufficient service usage history within your preferred project.
We suggest for you to make use of your current quotas and/or other resources readily available to serve your purposes for the meantime. To discuss further options on higher quota eligibility, please reach out to your Sales team [1] and provide this case ID ______  as reference. You may also direct them to reach out to us for questions or clarifications about your request."*

Does anyone know how to proceed? I appreciate any advice on this. Thank you!

Comment: Your options are to not use GPUs, wait until your account has matured or to contact the Sales team. Stack Overflow cannot help you with a vendor's policies.

Answer (score 1):

Some regions have better GPU availability than other so have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#gpus-list) and try [moving](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones) (or create a new) VM - you may have more luck with this.

Unfortunatelly as [@John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) said - there's nothing we can do if you were denied increased quotas. You try requesting increased quota for one region (not all) which should (IMHO) be more feasible.